# Dynamic Date Reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to crate a query that pulls the same date period for the Current Year (CY) and Prior Year (PY) with both being first of the year to today’s date. I want them dynamic so next year I don’t have to go in and update anything.

For CY I have:

```
Where CreatedOn between DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE(),1,1) and GETDATE()
```

For PY I am running into issues. I tried using a DATEADD to subtract a year from the above but that didn’t quite work.

I appreciate any help given.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. Showing just a `where` clause is not enough information for us to work with.

Comment: Neither "running into issues" nor "didn't quite work" are problem descriptions. What exactly happened, and why was that wrong?

Comment: Missing a close parenthesis   DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1) and GETDATE()

Comment: Why not `YEAR(GETDATE())-1` for past year?

Comment: @Larnu Thinking CY means Current Year

Comment: I worked that much out, @JohnCappelletti ! ;)

Comment: @Larnu On second read, you are correct

Comment: I am needing to pull a unique count of logins for cy being 1/1/20 to current date. Then I need py being same date range of cy but being 2019. But come next year. I was cy to pull 2021 and py to pull 2020.

Comment: I currently can’t pull anything for prior year because SSMS doesn’t like how I queried it.

Comment: What do "didn't quite work" and "doesn't like" mean? How did you query it? Please post the code you tried, sample data, desired results, and _actual_ error messages ("doesn't like" is very hard to diagnose). Also, do you want the same answer at any time during the day? If a login was created at 11 PM on October 5th of last year, is it in the result if you query today at 10 PM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
/* current year */
Where CreatedOn between datefromparts(year(getdate()),1,1) and getdate()

/* prior year */
Where CreatedOn between datefromparts(year(dateadd(year, -1, getdate())), 1, 1) and
                        datefromparts(year(dateadd(year, -1, getdate())), 12, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfYear,
   DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS EndOfYear
```

this should work

Comment: Why type `yy` instead of `YEAR`? https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: it is the same thing , you can use YEAR instead of yy , yy is abbreviation for YEAR , refer to Microsoft Documentation for mpre info :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: *I* know it is the same thing, does everyone who will use the code in the future? Why encourage less self-documenting methods to save two keystrokes? Did you click the link?